# replacing data in SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have multiple tables with corrupted data like this:

`Good data</title>and some random HTML<p></p><`

What I would like to do is only keep "Good data" in the cell and remove everything else. I thought I can just create a small project with EF and clean the db with C# but there might be a quicker solution with SQL only? Can you use regex or some kind of substring function in SQL?

I will manually look at the table and select the field that needs to run through the code, there is no need to automate that at this point.

Comment: Is it _good data_ always ends with `</title>` or `<` ?

Comment: So should this data never contain any HTML? In other words, you want to strip all the data starting at the first `<`?

Comment: Yes, it always starts with < and I want to remove everything that goes after that.

Comment: Starting defensive measures... [Don't try to parse this data with Regex](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/209259).

Comment: Defensive measure #2 -- make a backup copy of the data before trying to fix it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```sql
UPDATE dbo.SQLInjectionVictimTableName
  SET UnprotectedColumn = LEFT(UnprotectedColumn, CHARINDEX('<', UnprotectedColumn) - 1)
  WHERE UnprotectedColumn LIKE '%<%';
```

Answer (score 0):

If good data is consistently followed by `</`, you could use:

```
UPDATE YourTable
SET BadField = LEFT(Badfield,CHARINDEX('</',BadField)-1)
WHERE CHARINDEX('</',Badfield) > 0
```